# Prove that there is $c \in (a,b)$ for which $g(c) = 0$

Tags: calculus

> Suppose $f$ and $g$ are differentiable functions over an open interval $I$ satisfying $f'g = fg'$. Assume $a<b$ are adjacent roots of $f(x) = 0$ for some $a,b \in I$ and $g(a)g(b) \neq 0$. Prove that there is $c \in (a,b)$ for which $g(c) = 0$.

**Attempt**

We have that $f(x) = (x-a)(x-b)Q(x)$ and also that $$[(x-a)(x-b)Q'(x)+Q(x)((2x-(a+b))]g(x) = (x-a)(x-b)Q(x)g'(x).$$ I am not sure if this helps or not but I think Rolle's theorem might definitely help for this question.

Comment: Well, as a partial step:  there is some $c\in (a,b)$ with $g'(c)=0$.  To see that, take $h(x)=f(x)g(x)$ then $h(a)=0=h(b)$ and $h'=f'g+g'f=2g'f$.  Then the MVT finds us such a $c$ for which $h'(c)=0$ and since $a,b$ are adjacent roots of $f$, we must have $g'(c)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

$a,b$ are adjacent roots, implies $f\neq 0$ on $(a,b)$, suppose that $g\neq 0$ on $(a,b)$, on $(a,b)$ we have $f'/f=g'/g$ thus $log\mid f\mid =log\mid g\mid +c$ this implies that $f=Cg$ where $C$ is a non zero constant on $(a,b)$, this implies that $f=Cg$ on $[a,b]$, thus $g(a)=g(b)=0$. Contradiction.

Comment: How does $f = Cg$ imply that $g(a) = g(b) = 0$?

Comment: $f(a)=0=f(b)$ since $a$ and $b$ are roots, since $C\neq 0$, $f(a)=Cg(a)=0$ implies $g(a)=0$...

Comment: I'm not sure how that is a contradiction if you assumed $g \neq 0$ on $(a,b)$ and not $[a,b]$.

Comment: if f coincide with Cg on (a,b), they coincide on [a,b]

Comment: Better notation would be to suppose $g \neq 0 $ on $[a,b]$ because technically $g(a) = 0$ doesn't contradict here since you never said it was nonzero there.

Comment: Since $f(x)\ne 0$ for $x\in (a,b)$ we have $(g/f)=f g'-g f')/f^2=0$ on $(a,b)$ so $g/f$ is constant on $(a.b).$ So if $g$ is not constantly $ 0$ on $(a,b)$ then $ g\ne 0$ on $(a,b).$  But if $g$ is constantly $0$  on $(a,b) $ and if$f$ and $g$ are continuous at $a$ and $b$ we must have $g(a)=g(b)=0.$

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume that $g(c) \neq 0$ for all $c \in (a, b)$. Given that $g(a)g(b) \neq 0$ it follows that $g(x) \neq 0$ for all $x \in [a, b]$. And hence the function $F(x) = f(x)/g(x)$ is defined for all $x \in [a, b]$. Clearly we have $$F'(x) = \frac{g(x)f'(x) - f(x)g'(x)}{\{g(x)\}^{2}} = 0$$ and hence $F(x) = k$ for all $x \in [a, b]$ where $k$ is some constant. Therefore $f(x) = kg(x)$ and clearly $k \neq 0$ otherwise $f$ will be identically $0$ (note that the problem says that $a, b$ are adjacent roots of $f(x) = 0$ and hence it means that $f(x) \neq 0$ for all $x \in (a, b)$).

It thus follows that $g(x) = f(x)/k$ and clearly $g(a)g(b) = f(a)f(b)/k^{2} = 0$ which is a contradiction. Hence our assumption that $g(c) \neq 0$ for all $c \in (a, b)$ is wrong. And therefore there is at least one $c \in (a, b)$ for which $g(c) = 0$.